# Java instanciate class from Method object to invoke (Java Reflection)

Tags: java

So I am using this code statement to receive all methods that are annotated with a given annotation:

```
Set<Method> resources = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
```

So these Methods come from different classes.

What I want is to be able to use that collection later to invoke each of these functions like that:

```
for (Method method : resources) {
      // declaration of instance missing here
      method.invoke(instance);
}
```

The issue I am facing now is how can I create an instance of the class the method is originally coming from? Does the Method object even contain information on its class?

Apprecciate any help.

Comment: Yes, but for that I need the class name.

Comment: @luko0610 You can get the class with `getDeclaringClass()`

Comment: @Progman Great that solved it. Thanks!